# Zend Framework 1 .htaccess in subdirectory

Tags: zend-framework

I have use Zend framework 1 on Linux Apache web server and have to put it in the sub-folder named "go" and i put the .htaccess with these line in it(inside go folder) :

```
# Rewrite rules for Zend Framework 
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [QSA,L]
```

and what I've got after entering my domain.com/go is :

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

What i does wrong ?

after changing "/public" to "public" i also get the "not found" error .

I use subdomain like : go.domain.com for my app but i want to know why my first method don't work ? Don't .htaccess works on subdirectory ?

Comment: Is there a file at `http://example.com/public/index.php`?

Comment: There is not , I've told you i put it in sub directory named go .i have tested go/public instead of public but i get the "not found" error .

Answer (score 0):

you need to use RewriteBase in order for this to work

```
RewriteBase /go
```

and still put the .htaccess in the public folder , not anywhere else.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase

Answer (score 0):

The following solution worked for me:

First, place a **.htaccess** file in **/go** directory with following content

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [NC,L]
```

This will redirect every request made to **/go** url to public directory.

Next, make sure you don't have any `RewriteBase` in your **/go/public/.htaccess** file unless needed.

At last, create a controller plugin and put the following code in `routeStartup()`.

```
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()
                       ->getRequest()
                       ->setBaseUrl('/database/');
```

This last step will make it easy for you to add resources (css, js, images) to your HTML by using just `$this->baseUrl()` helper. You won't have to add **/go** with each file path.